# Drill thru report multivaled parameter passing

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report that I would like to add an action to drill through to another report. In the target report, I have a multivalued parameter that I need to pass 2 values to. I would like them to be literals that I set, not user selectable or based off of tablix data, but can't seem to find a way to do this. I know about the =JOIN(Field!col.value, ","), which I have used with great success, but I need to pass a set value of 8 and 3 that would be received by the target parameter as a selection of ID 8 (works on it's own) and a value of 3, but if I use =8 AND 3 or =8 OR 3 or =8,3 to pass both value to the parameter, it either mathematically adds the 2 together (value of 11 passed across) or I get errors in the syntax. Is there a method of passing these two static values to the parameter in the target report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to resolve my own problem. Was incredibly mess, but modified the dataset to include fixed value and referenced those in the parameter with a Split() function to send across the multiple values.